# Так undefined behavior или нет?

Tags: c

1) Обычный вариант, когда происходит Undefined Behavior:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = -10;
    int c = a + (a = 10);
    printf("%d",c);
    // undefined behavior
    return 0;
}
```

2) Похожий на следующий пункт вариант, здесь тоже undefined behavior:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = -10;
    int c = 0;
    if( a + (a = 10) || 0)
        c = 1;
    printf("%d %d",a,c);
    // undefined behavior
    return 0;
}
```

3) Но если мы поменяем второй операнд в условии на 1 то происходит магия:

```
int main(void) 
{
    int a = -10;
    int c = 0;
    if( a + (a = 10) || 1)
        c = 1;
    printf("%d %d",a,c);
    // выводит 10 1
    return 0;
}
```

Знаю про существование т.н. "ленивой логики", т.е. в случае операции && если первый операнд равен 0, то второй операнд опускается и не рассматривается. Но В данном случае этот "определяющий ленивую логику" операнд стоит справа. В чем же дело?

Если что, используется именно стандарт C99. Компилятор mingw32 gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никакой магии не происходит. В языке С выражение `a + (a = 10)` в вычислимом контексте всегда порождает undefined behavior. В каком окружении вы его использовали - значения не имеет. Третий вариант содержит тот же самый undefined behavior, что и первые два. Любое поведение вашей программы является проявлением этого undefined behavior, даже если вам показалось, что поведение вашей программы стало предсказуемым.

Каким образом вы "на глаз" отличили undefined behavior от "магии" и почему вы решили, что в третьем варианте нет undefined behavior - не ясно.

---

В качестве побочного замечания можно заметить, что в современном С++ выражение `a + (a = 10)` не порождает неопределенного поведения, а имеет *неспецифицированное* поведение из-за неспецифицированного порядка вычисления левого и правого операнда бинарного `+`. Так как компиляторы С и С++ зачастую реализуются на основе одного и того же "back end", вполне может получиться так, что С++ поведение "просачивается" и на территорию С. Но дела это не меняет: в С поведение не определено.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае **неопределенное поведение** возникает в по причине того, что значение **a** изменяется более одного раза между двумя точками следования.

Поскольку это происходит, нет никаких гарантий, что **(a = 10)** изменит состояние переменной до того, как произойдет операция **a + ...**. Вернее, нет вообще никаких гарантий на весь этот код.

Поскольку вы допустили ситуацию, которая порождает **неопределенное поведение**, весь ваш код становится **неопределенным**, что означает, что в этом коде может произойти все что угодно.

В том числе и выше по коду, а не только после выполнения операции с **неопределенным поведением**.

Допущенное **неопределенное поведение** в самом конце исходника может привести к аномалиям в работе корректных конструкций в начале исходника, а так же в иных исходниках, которые связаны с этим. В этом суть **неопределенного поведения**.

Компилятор всегда предполагает, что **неопределенного поведения** нет. С одной стороны, это позволяет ему выполнять широкий спектр оптимизаций. Но с другой, если **неопределенное поведение** все же было допущено, это нарушает внутренние алгоритмы работы компилятора, что становится причиной удивительных вещей.

Например:

- Могут выполниться обе ветки условия;
- Часть кода может быть заменена константой;
- Код может быть продублирован;
- Одна и та же переменная может одновременно иметь несколько значений;
- Объект может иметь состояние, которое невозможно для его типа;
- Компилятор может перепутать тип со значением;
- Компилятор может перепутать типы;
- Компилятор может перепутать время существования объектов.

И много всего другого.

Не нужно рассуждать о том, что, как и почему делает код с **неопределенным поведением**. Код может работать десятилетиями, а потом вдруг сломается.

*Или оживет...*

Comment: Вы уверены в своем ответе? На самом деле, программа, собранная разными компиляторами с разными ключами оптимизации на разных архитектурах вполне может давать разные результаты, но уже созданная, будет выводить одно и то же, сколько бы раз вы ее не выполняли.

Comment: Вы неправы. Согласно **Стандарту**, **неопределенное поведение** дает компилятору лицензию на генерацию несогласованного, противоречивого и дырявого кода, результатом которого может быть сравнение валидного используемого регистра с неиспользуемым, в котором хранится какое-то прошлое *случайное* значение. Этот код многие годы может иметь вполне ожидаемое поведение, но однажды в регистре окажется такое значение, которое приведет к цепочке операций, результатом которых станет перезапись адреса возврата или перезапись следующей инструкции.

Comment: И чем больше программа, тем сложнее и опаснее становится **неопределенное поведение**, которое возникает даже в простом случае **i = i++ + i++;**. Когда такая строка имеется в проекте из десяти строк кода, почти наверняка ничего страшного не произойдет (но гарантий нет). Если же эта строка имеется в проекте с сотнями тысяч строк кода, существует практически 100% вероятность того, что нарушенная логика работы компилятора и противоречивость его действий приведет к **очень удивительным вещам** даже в тех местах проекта, где выполняются очевидные и правильные действия.

Comment: Что тут сказать? В общем -- *"не по Сеньке шапка"*. Т.е. люди берутся за в самом деле сложную тему, а когда оказывается, что устранить глюки в своих программах они не в состоянии, то вносят их в документ, называемый СТАНДАРТ.

Answer (score -1):

Хороший тест на внимательность

```
int main(void){

int a = -10;
int c = a + (a = 10);
//присвоение в скобках выполняется ДО сложения. с = 20
printf("%d",c);
// undefined behavior
return 0;}
```

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = -10;
    int c = 0;
    if( a + (a = 10) || 0)
//Присвоили а = 10, прибавили ещё 10 (переменная а всё ещё 10) if всегда true -> c = 1 где ub?
        c = 1;
    printf("%d %d",a,c); //a = 10 c = 1
    // undefined behavior
    return 0;}
```

```
int main(void) 
{
    int a = -10;
    int c = 0;
    if( a + (a = 10) || 1)
// никакой магии, то же, что и в предыдущем примере
        c = 1;
    printf("%d %d",a,c);
    // выводит 10 1
    return 0;}
```

P.S. действительно UB. Первый пример: gcc здесь: **a + (a = 10)** сначала выполнит присвоение, затем сложение, независимо от оптимизации **(c = 20)**, а вот clang при включении оптимизации делает **c = -10 + 10 = 0**, без оптимизации **c = 20**. Короче UB в чистом виде.

Comment: Совершенно не верно. Скобки не имеют никакого влияния на порядок выполнения операций. Никакого "присвоение в скобках выполняется ДО сложения" в языке С нет и никогда не было. С - это не Java.

Comment: @AnT, я что-то не понимаю, похоже. Разве скобки не задают явно приоритет операций? Насколько я понимаю, выражение "a + (a = 10)" вызывает UB не потому, что + может вычисляться раньше = (он вычислится позже), а потому что значение первого операнда (a) может быть взято как до, так и после выполнения присваивания. Что не так?

Comment: @freim Задают. Но "приоритет операций" в С и С++ - это просто правила синтаксического разбора выражений. Приоритет операций диктует группировку операторов и операндов: он говорит, какие операнды относятся к каким операторам. Не более того. Порядок же фактического *вычисления* выражения к приоритету операций никакого отношения не имеет. А уж порядок и время материализации *побочных эффектов* - и подавно. Побочные эффекты к приоритету операций вообще никак не привязаны. Порядок выполнения задается секвенсингом: точками следования и т.п. Больше ничем.

Comment: @AnT, что-то вы настолько туманно выразились, что я вообще не понял о чем вы. Если о том, что я не совсем корректно употребил термин "приоритет операции" - да, но вопрос был о другом. Конкретно о заявлении, что "*скобки не имеют никакого влияния на порядок выполнения операций*" - что, правда? То есть если мы вместо `a+b*c` напишем `(a+b)*c` то это ни на что не повлияет?

Comment: @freim: Я не говорил, что приоритет "не на что не влияет". Я сказал, что приоритет указывает только на привязку операндов к их операторам. В выражении `a+b*c` приоритет говорит, что `b` является операндом `*`, а не операндом `+`. А `b*c` уже в свою очередь является операндом `+`. Это связывание позволяет нам определить *правильный результат* такого выражения. И все. Порядок вычисления этого выражения никакого отношения к этому связыванию и приоритету не имеет (!).

Comment: Компилятор может сначала вычислить `a+b`, потом умножить результат на `c`, а потом вычесть из полученного `a*(c-1)`, если ему так захочется.  Главное чтобы результат получился правильный. Но `a+b*c` - еще плохой пример, потому что в этом выражении нет *побочных эффектов*. Как только в выражении появляются операторы с *побочными эффектами*, независимость порядка выполнения от приоритетов операторов становится еще более очевидной.

Comment: В исходном `a + (a = 10)` побочный эффект как раз есть и здесь проблема проявляется намного ярче. Правила языка однозначно не говорят в какой момент `a` сменит свое значение на `10` и приоритеты операций (и скобки) на это никак не влияют вообще.

Comment: @AnT, факт состоит в том, ваше первоначальное заявление "*скобки не имеют никакого влияния на порядок выполнения операций*" совершенно неверно. Скобки _влияют_ на порядок выполнения и об этом вообще странно спорить. А речи о том, что на порядок влияют точки следования, а скобки влияют не на порядок выполнения, а на точки следования - все это просто схоластика, интересная только разработчикам компиляторов.

Comment: @freim: Нет, мое исходное утверждение совершенно верно. А ваше заявление о том, что "скобки влияют на точки следования" - полнейшая чушь. Ни в С, ни в С++ скобки **никогда и никак** не влияют на точки следования в выражениях с встроенными операторами. Именно поэтому скобки **никогда и никак** не влияют на порядок выполнения. Скобки меняют арифметическую семантику выражения и, разумеется, влияют на результирующий код. Но к "порядку выполнения" это не имеет никакого отношения, не говоря уже о порядке материализации побочных эффектов.

Comment: Чушь, написанная в ответ выше - это как раз пример той чуши, которая получается тогда, когда аффтар путает чисто синтаксические приоритеты (включая скобки) с порядком выполнения.

Comment: Вроде разобрался, поправьте если ошибаюсь. В строке **a = f(x) + s(x);**  f(x) и s(x) выполняются в произвольном порядке, и если одна из функций изменит x будет UB. Если мы хотим, чтобы f(x) выполнялась перед s(x), следует писать **a = f(x); a += s(x);**. Так?